# Three-dimensional simple Lie algebras over the rationals

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a three-dimensional $\mathbf Q$-vectorspace endowed with the structure of a simple Lie algebra. How many non-isomorphic such $\mathfrak g$ are there?

Over the complex numbers, the answer is 1, while over the reals there are two non-isomorphic ones.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78481/three-dimensional-simple-lie-algebras-over-the-rationals

Comment: More general discussion for extensions of $\mathbb Q$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3863613/96384.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many. As you know, there are two non-isomorphic three-dimensional Lie algebras over $\mathbb R$ that coincide over $\mathbb C$: $\mathfrak {sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathfrak {su}(2)$. To understand what happens over $\mathbb Q$, note that $\mathfrak {su}(2)$ is the derived subalgebra of the [quaternion algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra) over $\mathbb R$ (which is four-dimensional with a one-dimensional center).

So how many non-isomorphic quaternion algebras are there over $\mathbb Q$? There are infinitely many, though this is non-trivial. For every even set $S$ of [absolute values of $\mathbb Q$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem) (which are the real one and the [$p$-adic absolute values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)), there exists a unique quaternion algebra $D$ over $\mathbb Q$ such that for every $\nu\in S$, $D\otimes_\mathbb Q\mathbb Q_\nu$ is the unique quaternion algebra over $\mathbb Q_\nu$ (here $\mathbb Q_\nu$ denotes the completion of $\mathbb Q$ with respect to the absolute value $\nu$) and for every $\nu\not\in S$, $D\otimes_\mathbb Q\mathbb Q_\nu\simeq M_2(\mathbb Q_\nu)$, and all such quaternion algebras arise in this way. This is essentially an application of [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) (interpreted in terms of the [Hilbert symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol)).

Of course, the Lie algebra associated to $D$ is four-dimensional (and has a one-dimensional center), so take either the derived subalgebra of $D$ or, equivalently, take elements in $D$ with "reduced" trace zero to get a three-dimensional simple algebra. I can't quite rule out the existence of other algebras (the above are the "inner forms" of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb Q)$, there might be non-isomorphic "outer forms", but this is well outside my competency)

Comment: +1 Wow! I should have seen this, but failed to make the connection. Even I know that the different quaternion algebras you listed are pairwise non-isomorphic as $\mathbf{Q}$-algebras (they represent distinct classes in the Brauer group over the rationals). Is it obvious that this implies that the kernels of the reduced trace are then pairwise non-isomorphic as Lie algebras?

Comment: It tends to be better to provide a link to the question on MO than to do a different version. That way, updates, fixes and whatnot need only be done in one place.

Comment: Jyrki, let $\mathfrak {sl}_1(D)$ be the kernel of the reduced trace. Then $D\simeq \mathfrak {sl}_1(D)\oplus\mathbb Q$ as Lie algebras (since $\mathbb Q$ is the center of $D$ as an algebra). If $\mathfrak {sl}_1(D_1)\simeq \mathfrak {sl}_1(D_2)$, then $\mathfrak {sl}_1(D_1)\oplus\mathbb Q\simeq \mathfrak {sl}_1(D_2)\oplus\mathbb Q$, so $D_1\simeq D_2$.

Comment: Mariano, good point and duly noted.