# Semisimple elements in Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ ($k$ some base field) a
Lie subalgebra und let $\mathfrak{g}_s \subset \mathfrak{g} $ denote the
set of [*semisimple elements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Jordan_decomposition) of $\mathfrak{g}$. These are precisely the elements in $\mathfrak{g}$ which become
diagonalizable when passing to algebraic closure; ie diagonalizable
in $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_k \overline{k} $ under canonical inclusion $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{g} \otimes_k \overline{k} $.

Question: Which topological (with resp. to induced Zariski topology)
properties does the set $\mathfrak{g}_s $ of semisimple elements have? How to check that it cannot be Zariki open?

Motivation: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540456) Qiaochu Yuan conjectured that for $\mathfrak{g} := \mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C} $
the semisimple elements not form an open set.

Can it be proved generally that the subset of semisimple elements of
a Lie algebra in general cannot be Zariski open (except maybe in some 'pathological'
examples)? What do we know else about the topology of this subset? Is it
constructible/locally closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will focus on reductive Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ of semisimple rank $\geq 1$ (so they're not abelian, for which the question is easy).

In that case, the set of semisimple element is dense in $\mathfrak{g}$, but is neither open, nor closed, nor locally closed in the Zariski topology.

Density is easy to see in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, because any matrix whose characteristic polynomial has no multiple roots over $\bar{k}$ (such matrices form a non-empty open hence dense subset) is semisimple. In general, the same proof works, noting that the set of regular semisimple elements is a dense open subset of $\mathfrak{g}$.

The set of nilpotent elements $\mathcal{N}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ is Zariski closed (this being defined by the vanishing of all polynomial invariants of the Lie algebra); in the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ this is because nilpotency is defined by having characteristic polynomial coefficients equal to zero.
If $\mathfrak{g}_s$ were open in $\mathfrak{g}$, the set of semisimple nilpotent elements $\mathfrak{g}_s\cap \mathcal{N}$ would be open in $\mathcal{N}$. However, the only element that is both nilpotent and semisimple is zero, and $\{0\}$ is not open in $\mathcal{N}$. (The last sentences uses the fact that the semisimple rank is $\geq 1$, so $\mathcal{N}  \neq \{0\}$ because it contains for example regular nilpotent elements.)

It's now easy to see that $\mathfrak{g}_s$ can't be closed or even locally closed either. Indeed, if it would be, it would be open in its closure. But we showed that its closure is $\mathfrak{g}$ and we showed it's not open in $\mathfrak{g}$!

If you're looking for a positive result, the best thing I can think of is the following: let $G$ be a reductive group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and write $S = \mathfrak{g} // G$ for the space of invariant polynomials for the adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\pi \colon \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g} // G$ be the morphism of taking invariants. In the case of $G = SL_n$, $\mathfrak{g} // G$ is the space of monic polynomials with no $x^{n-1}$ term and $\pi$ is the morphism of sending a matrix to its characteristic polynomial. Then the theorem is (I think this is due to Kostant) that the intersection of $\mathfrak{g}_s$ with every fibre of $\pi$ is closed. (Taking the fibre above zero, you get the subvariety of nilpotent elements.) So somehow $\mathfrak{g}_s$ is well-behaved and closed in every fibre where you have fixed the invariants, but packaging all the fibres together gives a slightly weird set with bad topological properties.

If you want to read more about this, I highly recommend Kostant's papers 'Lie Group Representations on Polynomial Rings' and 'The Principal Three-Dimensional Subgroup and the Betti Numbers of a Complex Simple Lie Group'.

Comment: I agree with you that the sufficient & neccessary condition for nilpotency is
encoded in vanishing of coefficients of characteristic
polynomials.
But you wrote also that the nilpotent elements $\mathcal{N}$ in $g$ are Zariski closed
because it's defined by 'vanishing of all polynomial invariants of the Lie algebra'.
What do you mean by these 'all polynomial invariants of the Lie algebra'?

Comment: All polynomial functions on $\mathfrak{g}$ that are invariant under the action of $G$. See Kostant's papers.

Comment: @user7391733 examples include $\operatorname{tr}\operatorname{ad}^k(X) = 0$ for each $k$. Those equations cut out $\mathcal{N}$ for $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_n$.

Comment: It is maybe worth pointing out that the semi-simple elements are constructible. Indeed, fix a maximal torus $\mathfrak{t}$. One then has a natural map $G\times \mathfrak{t}\to \mathfrak{g}$ given by $(g,t)\mapsto gtg^{-1}$, and $\mathfrak{g}_\mathrm{ss}$ is the image of this map. Thus, $\mathfrak{g}_\mathrm{ss}$ is constructible by Chevalley's theorem. It is though, as you say, not locally closed. 

This issue is part and parcel with following issue: for a general scheme/variety $X$, what are the 'semi-simple elements' of $G(X)$? The inability to have a good answer for this (which follows

Comment: as the Jordan--Chevalley decomposition doesn't behave well in families) is highly related to the fact that $\mathfrak{g}_\mathrm{ss}$ doesn't have a natural scheme structure, which is related to the fact that it is not a locally closed subset of $\mathfrak{g}$. @user7391733